# Setting footer in first page of a pdf file using dynamic reports

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

I am using java 8 and dynamic reports 6.0.0. I am generating a pdf file. I have to set the footer only in the first page. 
There is a default method for setting the footer only in last page named lastPageFooter().

Code for adding footer in last page :

```
JasperReportBuilder report = new JasperReportBuilder();
report.lastPageFooter(cmp.text("footer text"));
```

Similarly I want to apply footer only for the first page. Please let me know how it can be one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some code :)